# C++ question about using a constructor initializer in a template

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, initializer

I have seen the following code written for a class template:

```
template<class T>
class NTree
{
private:
    T fKey;

public:
    NTree() : fKey(T()) 
    {
        //constructor
    }
};
```

The thing I don't understand is this fKey(T()). Couldn't we initialize it just be using fKey()? Sorry if this is a simple question, I couldn't find any other specific example of a case like this.

Comment: Should be `NTree() : fKey{T()}` even better.

Comment: This prevents compilation if `T` is not copy or move-constructable.